# Animaid turned my Timeline Brown and won't let me play animation

Tags: animation, add-on, graph-editor

While working, I mis-clicked and hit something with Animaid dropdown in the graph editor... While doing so, the timeline under my viewport and timeline in the graph editor turned brown (which isn't a big deal I guess.) but now I can't play my animation. When I hit play, the playhead would skip back to frame -100 and wouldn't move. Help?

AND I've tried setting the offset to Off, and unenabling the addon. But the problem persists...

Comment: Not really an answer, but I just got so caught up in the Animaid dropdown looking for answers, that I didn't think to look at my start and end frames of the animation. They were set to start at -100 and end at-100... My timelines are still brown though for some reason

Answer (score 1):

You may have accidentally hit <kbd>P</kbd> which is the shortcut for *Set Preview Range*, which allows you to play only a part of your timeline, just press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to undo it:

[image]